# atoi conversion to return a single digit value

Tags: c++, atoi

I have a character array like this :

```
+---+---+---+
|53.|.7.|...|
|6..|195|...|
|.98|...|.6.|
+---+---+---+
```

I am using an int array to store particular values at specific indexes.
For conversion i have used

```
            for(int i=0;i<27;i++)
        {
        inputNumArray[i]=atoi(&inputInitial[indexArray[i]]);        
        }
```

now the problem is my desired out put is :

```
5       3      0       0       7       0       0       0       0
6       0      0       1       9       5       0       0       0
0       9      8       0       0       0       0       6       0
```

and the code returns me this :

```
53      3       0       0       7       0       0       0       0
6       0       0       195     95      5       0       0       0
0       98      8       0       0       0       0       6       0
```

I assume the reason is that atoi scans till it finds character and for **atoi(&inputInitial[i])** it will read till i+1, i+2... and so on till it encounters an error. 
I want to restrict the atoi scanning to a single character only. Is it possible or shall i use some other function ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Don't use atoi, just use this:

```
if(isdigit(c))
    val = c - '0';
else
    val = 0
```

Comment: I would have propose (isdigit(c))?(c-'0'):0 but this one is ok ^^

Comment: I'm missing a semicolon and you don't, so yours is better...
I didn't use ?: because typedef1 is clearly a C novice, and I thought more readable was better in this case.
At least that's my formal excuse, it may be my prolonged stay with Python, though.

Comment: val = isdigit(c) ? c-'0' : 0; I believe.

Comment: @zmbq @ Ubiquite  BTW. are we doin c-'0' to remove the null character? Since it is a character not a string i do not think we must do -'0' . or what is the logic behind this..

Comment: Oh, please don't. It's impossible to read. Either place this in a function (someone suggested ctoi), or a macro:

#define ctoi(c) isdigit(c) ? c-'0'  : 0

and use it.

Comment: typedef1, you should read about the C char type and ASCII codes.

Comment: Final one that worked for me..... 

inputNumArray[i]=(isdigit(inputInitial[indexArray[i]]))?((inputInitial[indexArray[i]])-'0'):0;

Comment: Macro's are satanic in c++, they're far worse than a ternary operator. but typedef1's solution looks even more rediculous there I must admit.  Just write it out the way zmbq did originally.  I'll +1 the solution later if I can remember, I'm out of votes for the day :p

Comment: @w00te why does that sounds ridiculous... any specific reason why that shall not be used? I believe the operation cost for this particular syntax both the ways would be same ...

Comment: Taking something that's complex and cramming it into one line isn't good programming.  Someone else will look at the code in the future to maintain it (maybe even you) and they're going to have to decipher that line, all your brackets, all the pieces instead of just glancing across a nicely formatted if statement pleasantly.  It's just not good coding practice to write like that :p There's no benefit, it's just harder to read.

Comment: @typedef1, it's not rediculous, but it's very hard on the eyes. You want your programs to be easy on the eyes. It's usually a lot more important than saving a couple of cycles on a function call.

Comment: So it is one of the coding practice rather than relation to any space/time complexity... Got it.. thanks

Answer (score 1):

You arrumption about `atoi` is correct. If you want a single digit to be converted, you can create a string that contains just that:

```
char temp[2] = { inputInitial[indexArray[i]], '\0' );
inputNumArray[i] = atoi( temp );
```

Answer (score 0):

you can temporarily change the value of next character to 0 in your string so a to i just reads one digit.

Answer (score 0):

atoi expects a null terminated sequence of characters.

Better to write your own function that takes a single char, like:

```
int ctoi ( char ch ) {
    if ( ch >= '0' && ch <= '9' ) return ch - '0';
    return -1; // error
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The input format is not clear to me. However, here's what I'd do for an array:

```
char x[] = "12345678";
int out[] = new out[strlen(x)];

int* oit = out;
for (char* it=x; it < x+sizeof(x);)
     *oit++ = (*it++)-'0'


// out[] now contains char-by-char value as int
```